How to send an email using the Outlook Send Email API with Mail Composer(Nodemailer)?
We have a use case where users can send emails through our platform by integrating their Gmail and Outlook accounts. We've added an option for users to obtain a token from Google and Outlook for offline access.
For Gmail, the email-sending integration is implemented using Mailcomposer to create base64-encoded email content. By below code


const mailComposer = new MailComposer(mailOptions);
const message = await mailComposer.compile().build();
const rawMessage = Buffer.from(message).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');



The mailOptions include details such as from, to, cc, bcc, body, and attachments. The encoded message is then sent using the Gmail API:


const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
  userId: 'me',
  requestbody: { raw: rawMessage }
})



This allows us to send emails from a Gmail account. Now, we want to implement a similar flow for sending emails using the Outlook Send Email Graph API. My question is: Can we send an email through Outlook by converting the email object into base64 using Mailcomposer?
I followed this link to integrate it, but it doesn't contain detailed information.

Does an adapter exists for NodeMailer?

@Evert Yes, But we are using node mailer mail composer to convert our payload into MIME content

If you have a MimeMessage that is base64 encoded and you have an Accesstoken from the Graph (from that user) then a simple node.js send using the Graph SDK  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-nodeexpressapp/blob/main/graph-sample/routes/calendar.js would look like


var graph = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
require('isomorphic-fetch');

function getAuthenticatedClient() {
  // Initialize Graph client
  const client = graph.Client.init({
    authProvider: async (done) => {
      var accessToken = "eyJ0eX...";
      done(null, accessToken);
    }
  });

  return client;
}

async function sendMail() {
  var client = getAuthenticatedClient();
  var mimeMessage = "RnJvbT...."; 
  
   await client.api('/me/sendMail')
    .headers({ "content-type": "text/plain" })
    .post(mimeMessage);    
}

sendMail();




I have a object which contain all details like from, to, cc, bcc, subject, body and attachments, How can I convert that into MIME content?

Buffer.from(message).toString('base64') from the mailComposer will give you a rfc822 base64 string which is what the Graph can send, the other option would be take whatever object you have now and convert that to native Graph object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript
